# Problem related to harmonic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a, b, c$ be integers such that $a < b < c$. $c$ is a multiple of $b$. If $a, b, C$ are in HP and $a=20$. Then find all the possible values of $b$. I have taken $c= kb$ and got $b=(( 2k-1)20)÷k$. After this I have no clue of how to solve. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a$, $b$ and $c$ are in HP, $$b = \frac{2ca}{c+a}$$

Also $c = kb$ and $a = 20$

Hence $$b = \frac{40c}{c+20} = \frac{40kb}{kb+20} \implies k(40-b) = 20$$

Now we have only a few choices:
$$k = 1, 40-b = 20 \implies b = 20$$
$$k = 2, 40-b = 10 \implies b = 30$$
$$k = 4, 40-b = 5 \implies b = 35$$
$$k = 5, 40-b = 4 \implies b = 36$$
$$k = 10, 40-b = 2 \implies b = 38$$
$$k = 20, 40-b = 1 \implies b = 39$$

Consider the relevant ones from the above!

Comment: C=1 is not possible bcuz it is mentioned that B is less than c